# I am working on Full Calendar with Vue.js: Trying to add functionalities on it but not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am started working on Full Calender with Vue. I tried but not able to adopt some of the functionalities on Full Calendar. Like:

1. How to add columnHeaderFormat like- for Month - Monday, Tuesday , for week- Mon 08/11
2. How to show only scheduled timing on week Calendar. e.g.- if event is from 2pm to 4pm then only this 2hours should be shown for Week/day Calendar.
3. How to add Default Date in Full Calendar.
4. How to add event Limit in FC.

   CODE:
   TEMPLATE: `<full-calendar class="calendar" :options="calendarOptions"/>`

SCRIPT:
data() {

```
    return {
      calendarOptions: {
        plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, listPlugin, timeGridPlugin],
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        headerToolbar: {
          left: 'today prev,next',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
        },
        events: this.eventDates,
        eventDisplay: 'block',
        displayEventTime: false,
        allDaySlot: false
}
```

**CodeSandBox Link**: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-fullcalendar-scheduler-example-forked-0vgy6?file=/components/Calendar.vue

Kindly help me out on this. Your answer would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: can you create a JSFiddle with your code and share it

Comment: @DevZer0 Thanks for your prompt response. I have attached my code in CodeSandBox. Please find the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-fullcalendar-scheduler-example-forked-0vgy6?file=/components/Calendar.vue . Awaiting for your reply

Comment: have you checked the suggestions here https://vcalendar.io/i18n.html

Comment: @DevZer0 I checked but didn't get much. Also I am working with Full-Calendar not V-Calendar.

Answer (score 1):

based on the documentation here https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dayHeaderFormat

```
// like 'Mon', for month view
{ weekday: 'short' }

// like 'Mon 9/7', for week views
{ weekday: 'short', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', omitCommas: true }

// like 'Monday', for day views
{ weekday: 'long' }
```

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  views: {
    dayGrid: {
      weekday: 'long'
    }
  }
});
```

to apply to your code

```
return {
      calendarOptions: {
        views: {
           dayGrid: {
              weekday: 'long'
           }
        },
        plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, listPlugin, timeGridPlugin],
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        headerToolbar: {
          left: 'today prev,next',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
        },
        events: this.eventDates,
        eventDisplay: 'block',
        displayEventTime: false,
        allDaySlot: false
}
```

Comment: Yes I have gone through this. but i am not understanding how can I apply to my above Code's Calendar Option structure. Can you please check!

Comment: try my new response its part of Calendar options

Comment: it didn't worked . Still the format is ddd (Mon, Tue...) on Month view.

Comment: basically you have to figure out how to pass view options

Comment: Thanks @DevZer0 for your support and help. I searched and tried a lot now it got fixed. We need to add some properties on the Calendar Option.

Comment: can you share the updated code as an answer to your own question

Comment: Yes already posted yesterday. Please check below.

Answer (score 1):

### For default load, event limit and day format:

- initialDate: '2021-11-01'
- dayMaxEvents: 2,
- dayHeaderFormat: {   weekday: 'long', month: 'numeric', day:
  'numeric', omitCommas: true }

consolidate code:

```
>  data() {
>     return {
>       calendarOptions: {
>         plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, listPlugin, timeGridPlugin],
>         initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
>         headerToolbar: {
>           left: 'today prev,next',
>           center: 'title',
>           right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
>         },
>         events: this.eventDates,
>         eventDisplay: 'block',
>         displayEventTime: false,
>         allDaySlot: false,
>         initialDate: this.startingDate,
>         dayMaxEvents: 2,
>         dayHeaderFormat: {
>           weekday: 'long', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', omitCommas: true
>         },
>         expandRows: true,
>         slotEventOverlap: false,
>         buttonText: {
>           today: 'Today',
>           month: 'Month',
>           week: 'Week',
>           day: 'Day'
>         }
>       }
>     };   
}
```